# Why does fmt.Prinft() log `const` in other package like memory address?

Tags: go, memory-management

How did `fmt.Printf()` treat `%x?` when the parameter is a `var` or `const`. I read from books that `const` has no `Type` before been specified, it is hard to understand.

```golang
const AValue int32 = 1049088

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#x\n", 1049088)
    fmt.Printf("%#x\n", AValue)

    fmt.Printf("%#x\n", int(time.Friday))
    fmt.Printf("%#x\n", time.Friday)
}
```

logs :

`0x100200 // 1049088`
`0x100200 // AValue`
`0x5 // int(time.Friday)`
`0x467269646179 // time.Friday is a type Weekday int`

```
Is `0x467269646179` some kind address of time.Friday?
```

Comment: Why do you think that's a memory address? You're telling it to format as hexidecimal, so that's what it does.

Comment: A go newbie.Tanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt):

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting
> considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces.
> In order of application:
> ...
> 5. If an operand implements method `String()` string, that method **will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
> formatted as required by the verb (if any)**.

For `string` the verb formatting is defined as:

```
%s  the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice
%q  a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax
%x  base 16, lower-case, two characters per byte
%X  base 16, upper-case, two characters per byte
```

So `0x467269646179` is the `base 16, lower-case, two characters per byte` of the output of `time.Friday.String()`.

https://play.golang.org/p/avV-X2uiL1D

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a lot.